# ExpandableListView guidance needed

Tags: android

I want to:

1. Integrate this expandable list as a part of a layout and not the
   only element of the layout as it is now.
2. Use XML layouts for the generic view and for the child view.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you have done???\

Comment: look at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) and a little [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=using+an+expandable+listview+tutorial&oq=using+an+expandable+listview+tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57.11451j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) can help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job for you. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/